# Check if a function exists in a class before calling call_user_func()

Tags: php

In the following code I call a class with `call_user_func()`.

```
if(file_exists('controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php')) {
    require('controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php');
    call_user_func(array($this->controller, $this->view));
} else {
    echo 'error: controller not exists <br/>'. 'controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php';
}
```

Let’s say that the controller has the following code.

```
class test {

    static function test_function() {
        echo 'test';
    }

}
```

When I call `call_user_func('test', 'test_function')` there isn't any problem. But when I call a function that does not exist, it does not work. Now I want to check first if the function in the class `test` does exist, before I call the function `call_user_func`.

Is there a function that checks if a function exists in an class or is there another way I can check this?

Comment: [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: Not every existing method is callable -> [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php)

Comment: Not every callable method can really be called. E.g. calling not-static method statically.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You're looking for [`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) for starters. But what you *should* check, too is whether or not the method is *callable*. This is done by the helpfully named [`is_callable`](http://php.net/is_callable) function:

```
if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->view)
    && is_callable(array($this->controller, $this->view)))
{
    call_user_func(
        array($this->controller, $this->view)
    );
}
```

But that's just the start of things. Your snippet contains explicit `require` calls, which suggests you're not using an [*autoloader*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). 
What's more: all you're doing is check `file_exists`, not if the class was already loaded. Your code, then, will generate a fatal error if, per chance your snippet gets executed twice with the same values for `$this->controller`. 
Begin fixing this by, in the very least, changing your `require` to [`require_once`](http://www.php.net/require_once)...

Comment: Do you need to call `method_exists()` if you are calling `is_callable()` anyway?

Comment: @w3d: `is_callable` could, theoretically return `true` even if you're not calling a method (closures assigned to properties). doing both checks is perhaps a tad paranoid, but it's the safest way. Besides, last I checked, `method_exists` performed better, so if that returns false, `is_callable` will not be called (micro-optimization, I know, but still...). That's not to say that you don't have a point, though, but I figure both functions are worth mentioning in this context...

Comment: Both `is_callable` and `method_exists` return `true` when you check a not-static method with a class name, e.g. `class Controller { public function view() {} } is_callable(['Controller', 'view']);`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the PHP function [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
if (method_exists('ClassName', 'method_name'))
call_user_func(etc...);
```

or also:

```
if (method_exists($class_instance, 'method_name'))
call_user_func(etc...);
```

Comment: Great It you made it to understand very simple.

Answer (score 4):

From PHP 5.3, you can also use:

```
if(method_exists($this, $model))
    return forward_static_call([$this, $model], $extra, $parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `method_exists($this->controller, $this->view)`. For your example:

```
if(file_exists('controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php') && 
   method_exists($this->controller,$this->view)) {

    require('controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php');
    call_user_func(array($this->controller, $this->view));

} else {
    echo 'error: controller or function not exists <br/>'. 'controller/' . $this->controller . '.controller.php';
}
```

Comment: Although you'd need to call `method_exists()` _after_ you've included the class file.