# PHP if method exists before require_once()

Tags: php

want to check if method i took from uri is exist in UserController class  then require the class

i find some function

```
file_exists()

class_exists()
```

but if i use file_exists() when request is ( user/test)

the method not exist and error comes

**uri =>  controller / method / params**

```
$parts = getUriExplode();
$controller = $parts[0];
$method = $parts[1];

$params = array();
for ($i=2 ; $i<count($parts) ;$i++){
    $params[] = $parts[$i];
}
$controllerClassName = ucfirst($controller) . "Controller";
$controllerFilePath = "/mvc/controller/" . $controller . ".php";


if( method exists ){

    require_once($controllerFilePath);
    $controllerInstance = new $controllerClassName();
    call_user_func_array(array($controllerInstance,$method),$params);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if function exists in class before calling call\_user\_func()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537423/check-if-function-exists-in-class-before-calling-call-user-func)

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the class to be able to check if the method exists, and pass [proper parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) to the function.

```
require_once($controllerFilePath);
// You can use $controllerInstance too, but there's no need if the method does not exist
if(method_exists($controllerClassName, $method)) {
    $controllerInstance = new $controllerClassName();
    call_user_func_array(array($controllerInstance, $method), $params);
}
```

However, as pointed out in the comments by @MadhurBhaiya, not every method can be called (as is the case with `private` methods) or have to exist (when the magic `__call()` has been defined).

To account for this you can use:

```
if (is_callable("$controllerClassName::$method"))
```

Comment: Not every function is callable. Use `is_callable` method alongside `method_exists`

Answer (score 0):

there is a function for this called

```
method_exists(object, string method_name)
```

object =  is a class instance 
method_name = method name as string
see the example below

```
<?php

    $directory = new Directory();
    var_dump(method_exists($directory,'read'));
?>
```

if this method exits output is true
this means var dump will show you boolean true

for more information checkout this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php